# How do I prevent accidental global name space pollution with javascript eval?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple REPL (Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop) implementation in JavaScript. I am able to isolate code and calling context like so:

```
var sandbox = {
  // Allow the input code to use predefined helper functions
  // without the preceding use of the this keyword.
  helper_fn: function() { alert("foo"); }
};

var func = new Function("with (this) { " + user_inputed_code + " }");
func.call(sandbox);
```

Now it closes the `user_inputed_code` so that `this` referers to `sandbox` and if the inputted code accesses or mutates `this` it is affecting `sandbox`.

However, I noticed that if the imputed code were to accidentally forget to preface a variable assignment with the keyword `var` that the global namespace get polluted.

Is there anyway to prevent this? If so how (maybe a regexp?)? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Can you *eval* the code in a separate frame or window that has a separate *global* object? Incidentally, in ECAMScript, "context" is used in relation to [*execution context*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3). A particular execution context's *this* parameter is only one small part of "context" that refers to all the parameters and variables, scope chain, etc.

Comment: I plan to use this in a Titanium project. So frames are not available. However freeze might work. Will have to see if the runtime supports that.

Comment: Can you run the code in strict mode? That way assignment to undeclared variables will throw an error. You can't use *with* though. And users can still create globals using `window.foo = ...`.

Comment: @Sukima I just noticed that you said you're using Titanium, it lets you create a new separate execution context with the createWindow command. Your application can have multiple execution contexts. New execution contexts are typically created by opening a new window that points to an external URL in its url property: `Ti.UI.createWindow({url:'yourscriptfile.js'}).open();` You can message pass between contexts. See this guide: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/12/titanium-guides-project-js-environment.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to provide two completely different approaches from what others discussed here. They are both drastic, and are useful when you want to relatively isolate your environment.

- The easiest technique that works in all browsers is to probably create an iframe, and append script tags to it. (Note, a really overzealous iframe can still get past that if they're in the same domain, at least in older browsers). I discuss that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681460/making-a-same-domain-iframe-secure).
- Use web Workers, which have an isolated environment by default and have no access to the global object of the main execution thread. I discuss that [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660145/is-it-possible-to-make-a-secure-jsonp-request).

More specifically, if you're building a REPL take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409639/how-to-execute-different-partsof-the-js-code-in-one-scope/15409716#15409716) where we discuss and I explain how to eval code in the same scope but outside the global scope, using the first approach of iframes.

(I assumed a browser, in node you can simple use the vm module and select the context in runInContext)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a way with `"use strict"` and without `Object.freeze`. You have to manually replace the global namespace with your own sandbox object:

```
var sandbox, module, func, output;
// Empty object or with defined methods / properties
// you want to expose as globals.
sandbox = {};
// A reference to an object you WANT to provide safe
// access to. In this example it's just an empty object.
module = {};
// A better version of eval:
func = new Function("module", "with(this){return(function(module,global,window){\"use strict\";return eval(\"" + code + "\");})(module,this,this)}");
output = func.call(sandbox, module);
```

This code allows global and window to refer to a sandboxed object instead of the global name space. It masquerades the variables `global` and `window` as the sandbox object and the use of `"use strict"` will cause it to throw an exception if the input missed the use of `var`. It also wraps the function in a `with` statement to make the methods and properties defined in the sandbox object to work as if they were preceded by `this.`. To see an implementation example (with test specs) check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/6088546).

Thank you all for your ideas. Hope this answer helps others.

Comment: What if `code` calls another function and that function is not in strict mode? Or executes `eval` itself?

Comment: Aside from some sickening regular expressions I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: See my answer, I provide two ways to prevent that as well as links to repl implementations.

Comment: Curious, could a `var window = {};` be placed at the beginning of the evaluated function?